# How to create a remote TFSGIT Repo programatically?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any API I could use in order to create a new GIT Repo in the remote TFS Server?

Ideally something like

```
New-GitRepo -server myServer -team team1 -name myRepo
```

if there isn't a powershell api, i can do with a RESTful HTTP endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the docs:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories#create-a-repository

Use the REST API:

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/?api-version={version}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": {string},
  "project": {
    "id": {guid}
  }
}
```

Though I don't know exactly from which TFS version this API became available. Given you tagged TFS2015 and the API compatibility has changed from RTM to update 3.